# Concat function in azure function template is not executed

Tags: azure

```
{
   "bindings":[
      {
         "topicName":"%TOPIC_NAME%",
         "connection":"SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING",
         "name":"vCalcEvent",
         "subscriptionName":"%LMS_PUBLISH_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME%",
         "type":"serviceBusTrigger",
         "direction":"in"
      },
      {
         "name":"myOutputBlob",
         "type":"blob",
         "path":"archive/{DateTime:yyyyMMdd}/**concat**({metaData.fileName},'')_{DateTime:yyyyMMddHHmmss}_{rand-guid}.json",
         "connection":"LMS_STORAGE_SHAREPOINT_CONNECTION_STRING",
         "direction":"out"
      }
   ],
   "scriptFile":"../dist/az-func-vc-lms-publish/index.js"
}
```

Above function concat is not being executed properly, the result when trying to insert into the container is **[replace(testdata.xlsb,'.xlsb','')]_20230613221813_a4bdd27e-3aa1-4fba-8144-9297f2d39ad**

Answer (score 0):

> Concat function in azure function template is not executed

These types  are not supported in **function.json** of azure function.

If you give anything as below :

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "out/{DateTime:yyyyMMdd}/**concat**(rand-guid)_{DateTime:yyyyMMddHHmmss}_{rand-guid}.json",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob"
    }
  ]
}
```

You will get output as this only(this is expected behavior as this takes it as a string value not as function):

**`**concat**(rand-guid)_20230615065402_40fca2c7-a250-4833-841b-4dd58ddc838f.json`**

[image]

[image]

If you want to use concats , replaces, etc. You need to use those functions inside the function app and then you can store that value in a variable and then you can give it has  a name of file by passing it in functions.json.